# I am trying to get primefaces to show up in the project facet for websphere 8.0

Tags: java, jsf-2, primefaces, websphere

I am trying to get primefaces to show up in the project facet for Websphere 8.0. Can someone explain How this is achieved.

Comment: Uhm. PrimeFaces is a JSF based component library. Just select JSF facet? Or, if you're absolutely positive that you should have a PrimeFaces facet, where did you read about a PrimeFaces facet? Never heard of it and they don't seem to promote any Eclipse-specific plugins.

Comment: I'm not aware of a PrimeFaces facet as well.